# How to go back to the fragment in an activity which launched the activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation, fragment

If i have 4 fragments in my main activity .. if i launch an activity from any one of them. Then how do i go back to that last fragment from the new activity ? E.g Activity A has 1 2 3 and 4 fragment. i launch Activity B from fragment 3. now i want to go back to Activity A but in fragment 4 .. if i just use finish() activity or the the home button in appbar .. i goto to Activity A fragment 1.. but i want it to be Activity A fragment 3.. Any help ? i want that back arrow in the appbar to accomplish this functionality ? or when in any case im done with this activity ?

Comment: How to you return from the launched `Activity` to the previous one? Just calling `finish()` or using the BACK button should return you to the previous `Activity` in the state it was when you left it.

Comment: Yes finish does the trick. if you put it as an answer ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just calling `finish()` or using the BACK button should return you to the previous Activity in the state it was when you left it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `transaction.addToBackstack(null)` before committing your fragments transactions.

Comment: Can you please explain this .. i mean .. im going from one activity to another .. im not doing any fragment transaction ? i only do a transaction when i go from one fragment to another .. and even that i dont do .. i have bottom navigation to handle that ?